# How to make SAP Cloud SDK OData client send request call to Spring MockMVC fake test servlet and get the response?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We are using Spring MockMVC to test our OData endpoints of our application.

The headache part of such integration test is, every time we have to construct the complex OData query url string by ourselves and also we have to serialize the JSON response from MockMVC api to Java pojo objects by ourselves, in order to verify the response content.

Since SAP Cloud SDK provides a type-safed way to consume OData service, we also want to use it in our integration test. However, the problem is how to make SAP Cloud SDK OData client to send request to the Spring fake test servlet then? Is that possible?

It works if we add the annotation

```
webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
```

to start a real server in the integration test (then we can make Cloud SDK send request to "localhost:port") but as we all know this approach is much slower than using a fake Spring web context.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly, in your test you are **not** interacting with a "real" OData service, but you want to interact with a "fake" endpoint?

If you want to serve OData responses via HTTP during tests, then I would advise *against Spring MVC* (because AFAIK there is no HTTP interaction) and *Spring Servlets* (because of complexity for testing). For testing your application you can obviously do what ever works for you. But for the OData interaction via HTTP, I would suggest using [WireMock](https://wiremock.org/) instead. It temporarily starts a real server with `localhost:port`, that can be addressed by *SAP Cloud SDK* productive code.

In case you are using the *Destination* API and you want to use a "local" destination during your tests, please checkout *[Registering destinations during runtime](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/connectivity/destination-service#registering-destinations-at-runtime)*.

---

There are of course other ways to mock test data for OData interaction. Customizing the whole HTTP interaction like above can be considered excessive. Please consider mocking your OData adapters classes (and other outbound related implementations) during local tests. In the end, you would not test *SAP Cloud SDK* code, but your own application code, of course :)

Comment: I feel he's building one OData service, and the purpose of the test is to cover every endpoint he built, including methods, URLs and payloads, which is more or less like unit tests. The reason he uses SDK for this case is to build the URLs or payloads easily and HTTP interaction is out of the scope.

Comment: Hi @JunjieTang, you are right, I'm building some OData service and want to write some integration tests (someone calls component tests) to cover them. We are using Spring MockMVC.

Comment: I don't fully understand the test scope then. Not sure we can give a qualitative response without some sample code / repo link.

Comment: > "test to cover every endpoint he built, including methods, URLs and payloads, [...]  and HTTP interaction is out of the scope" - I think this is not possible. For that I can only suggest "to start a real server" locally as pointed out in the original question. I'm not aware of a shortcut / cheat code here.